# Resummation of a series from an integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, divergent-series

Let's consider the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-gx^2-x}dx$$
If I'm not mistaken, 
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-gx^2-x}dx=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2\sqrt g}e^{1/4g}\left(1-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt g}\right) \right)$$
Now I want to try a different method : let's develop the exponential in series :
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-gx^2-x}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n g^n}{n!}x^{2n}\right)e^{-x} dx$$
I want to swap the series and integral (which is forbidden here), I get the series :
$$\sum_n\frac{(-1)^n g^n}{n!} \int_0^{\infty} x^{2n}e^{-x} dx=\sum_n\frac{(-1)^n g^n}{n!}(2n)!$$
which is clearly divergent for all $g$.

My question is : is there a method to resum (Borel resummation?) this series and get back to the value of the original integral? Are all resummation (which works) methods going to give me the same result?

I'd like to do the same thing with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-gx^4-x^2)dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt g}\exp(1/8g)K_{1/4}(1/8g)$ and by developing in powers of $g$ I get the series :
$$\sum_n\frac{(-1)^n g^n}{n!}\Gamma\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Not sure if this is the only route you want to go down. However, you might try completeing the square if you just want to evaluate the integral nicely

Comment: @TylerHG: I'm not sure how helpful completing the square will be in this case, since the bounds of integration $[0,\infty)$ aren't preserved under translations.

Comment: I already can evaluate the integral (by using erf function) and the formula is indeed obtained by completing the square. However I want to know if I can compute it through the series development.